# How to make sure that I'll not call my API again (from a button click) if there's already an API call in progress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I made this piece of code and I have a question about it.

**See snippet below before reading the question.**

It mimicks the **like/dislike** action of a blog post by calling an API and I think it's working as intended, but I don't know exactly why. I think this is intriguing.

Here is my train of thought:

- After everything renders, I have a 'click' listener attached to the button and it will be handled by my function `toggleLike`
- Before I click the button for the first time, my `toggleLike` function, at this point, it **was created during the last render**, when the value of `props.likeInProgress` was `false`. Therefore, if I execute this function 10 times at this point, it will execute thinking that `props.likeInProgress` is `false`.
- I know that **once the button is clicked**, the first thing that `toggleLike` will do it's to set `likeInProgress` to `true`, by calling `setLikeInProgress(true);` and that will prevent me from making two API calls one on top of the other.
- But I also know that `setState` **might not trigger a re-render immediatelly**, so what is stopping me from clicking insanely fast and end up calling the API two, or three times concurrently?

**QUESTION**

The fact is that it seems impossible to click fast enough and trigger more than one API call at the same time (running concurrently). And that's what I want to achieve.

But what I want to know: is this a matter of speed? **Is React updating the state so fast that it's impossible to click the button a second time before the `toggleFunction` has been recreated (now with `props.likeInProgress` as true)?** Or the order that the code is executed prevents that from happening completely and it has nothing to do with speed?

**MORE EXPLANATION:**

When you click 2 times really fast, the fact that you see that log of `There is a call in progress` means that React has already re-rendered everything and now the `toggleLike` function is seeing `props.likeInProgress` as `true`. If it's a matter of speed and you click insanely fast you'd be able to execute the very same `toggleLike` from your first click, which sees `props.likeInProgress` as `false`, and that would lead into you calling the API a second time.

```js
function App() {
  
  //console.log('Rendering App...');

  // STATE TO MONITOR THE LIKE API CALL IN PROGRESS
  const [likeInProgress,setLikeInProgress] = React.useState(false);
  
  // STATE TO KNOW WHETHER A POST HAS BEEN LIKED OR NOT
  const [hasLiked,setHasLiked] = React.useState(false);
  
  // REF TO KEEP TRACK OF THE LIKE COUNT
  const likeCount_ref = React.useRef(15);
  
  // THIS IS TO MOCK A LIKE API CALL (1000 ms DELAY ASYNC)
  function mockLikeAPI(action) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve('Done');
      },1000);
    });
  }

  // THIS IS THE CALL TO THE LIKE API
  function callMockLikeAPI(action) {
    setLikeInProgress(true);                              // SET STATE likeInProgress TO 'TRUE'
    mockLikeAPI(action).then(()=> {                       // CALL THE API
      likeCount_ref.current = action === 'LIKE' ?         // UPDATE COUNTER ACCORDINGLY
        likeCount_ref.current + 1 
      : likeCount_ref.current - 1;
      action === 'LIKE' ? setHasLiked(true) : setHasLiked(false);   // UPDATE hasLiked STATE
      setLikeInProgress(false);
    });
  }

  return(
    <BlogPost
      likeCount={likeCount_ref.current}
      likeInProgress={likeInProgress}
      hasLiked={hasLiked}
      callMockLikeAPI={callMockLikeAPI}
    />
  );
}

function BlogPost(props) {

  //console.log('Rendering BlogPost...');
  
  // FUNCTION TO TOGGLE THE LIKE OF THE POST
  function toggleLike() {
    if (props.likeInProgress) {                       // IF THERE'S A LIKE IN PROGRESS
      console.log('There is a call in progress...');  // LOG
      return;                                         // DO NOTHING. RETURN;
    }
    else {                                        // ELSE
      console.log('I will call the API now...');  // LOG
      props.hasLiked === false ?                  // CALL THE API WITH THE PROPER ACTION
        props.callMockLikeAPI('LIKE') 
      : props.callMockLikeAPI('DISLIKE');
    }
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am a Blog Post</div>
      <div>Like Count: {props.likeCount}</div>
      <button onClick={toggleLike}>{props.hasLiked === false ? 'Like' : 'Dislike'}</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Sorry about the broad question title. I didn't know how to describe it in a single sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about... If I click twice in a row I get "There is a call in progress..." logged to the console.... I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: @MattOestreich sorry if I wasn't clear. The fact that you see that log `There is a call in progress` means that React has already re-rendered everything and now the `toggleLike` function is seeing `props.likeInProgress` as `true`. If it's a matter of speed and you click insanely fast you'd be able to execute the very same `toggleLike` from your first click, which sees `props.likeInProgress` as `false`, and that would lead into you calling the API a second time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. If you remove that `if/else` from `toggleLike`, and just used the contents of the `else` as the entire function, you would be able to call the API twice.... I'm not sure what you're confused about, but sending multiple API requests has nothing to do with rerendering...

Comment: My point is that I don't want to send multiple API requests. Only 1 at a time. How can I be sure of that?

Comment: By doing exactly what you're doing....

Comment: @MattOestreich Thanks for your interest in my question. The way I'm doing seems to be working. But I want to know why it's working. If it has something to do with speed, that it's not good enough. I want to be 100% sure that it's impossible to make that API call concurrently. Do you have any idea of how I can be sure of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950

> In current release, they will be batched together if you are inside a
>   React event handler. React batches all setStates done during a React
>   event handler, and applies them just before exiting its own browser
>   event handler.

For certain events, including click, react ensures render before exiting the event handler. So after your first click, render will happen with `likeInProgress = true` before next onClick is fired.

Answer (score 2):

hide the button once the user clicks it, replace it with a gif loader, then show it again once the call is finished. You will need to implement a call back on the network call. This will gaurantee that the user cannot `call the api twice` as the button with the onclick event is now hidden.

```
btnWithNetCall(parameter1){
   // hide your button via attribute or css
   attemptAPIcall(param1, function(response){
       //show your button again after checking what happened with response
   })
} 


attemptAPIcall(param1, callback){
  // fire callback with pertinent data after doing networky thing
  callback(someSortOfReponseData)
}
```

Comment: How would I hide it? Based on a `state` passed down as `props` like `likeInProgress` ?

Comment: callMockLikeAPI will need a callback function, let me edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about a click in between renders..

You can disable the button after click and add some sort of a progress bar/loader..

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    likeInProgress: false,
    hasLiked: false,
    likes: 15
  });

  function mockLikeAPI(action) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("Done"), 1000));
  }

  async function callMockLikeAPI(action) {
    setState(cs => ({ ...cs, likeInProgress: true }));
    await mockLikeAPI(action);
    let actionIsLike = action === "LIKE";
    setState({
      likeInProgress: false,
      hasLiked: actionIsLike,
      likes: actionIsLike ? state.likes + 1 : state.likes - 1,
    });
  }

  return (
    <BlogPost
      likeCount={state.likes}
      likeInProgress={state.likeInProgress}
      hasLiked={state.hasLiked}
      callMockLikeAPI={callMockLikeAPI}
    />
  );
}

function BlogPost(props) {
  function toggleLike() {
    if (props.likeInProgress) {
      return;
    } else {
      props.hasLiked === false
        ? props.callMockLikeAPI("LIKE")
        : props.callMockLikeAPI("DISLIKE");
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am a Blog Post</div>
      <div>Like Count: {props.likeCount}</div>
      <button disabled={props.likeInProgress} onClick={toggleLike}>
        {props.hasLiked === false ? "Like" : "Dislike"}
        {props.likeInProgress ? <div className='loader' /> : ''}
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3; 
  border-top: 1px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```